# should a return variable of a class method be stored in the class itself or not?

Tags: python, oop, object, scope, coding-style

The answer to this question is probably going to depend on the exact circumstances, but as I do not have clever thoughts about it anyway, I thought it would be good to post it here.

Assume we have a class such as the following piece. The code is in Python, but could as well be in any other OO-language.

```
class Dashboard():
def __init__(self, length_dashboard):
    self.length = length_dashboard

# create dashboard with month codes
def create_dashboard(self):
    db = ['']*self.length
    db[0] = foo()
    for item in range(1, self.length-1):
        db[item] = bar(item-1)
    return db
```

Is this good coding style? Or is it better to lock up the return value in one of the variables of the instance?:

```
class Dashboard():
def __init__(self, length_dashboard):
    self.length = length_dashboard
    self.db

# create dashboard with month codes
def create_dashboard(self):
    self.db = ['']*self.length
    self.db[0] = foo()
    for item in range(1, self.length-1):
        self.db[item] = bar(item-1)
    return self.db
```

Comment: I think this has more to do with what should be made an instance field and less about returning. Does returning have any significance to the question?

Comment: No, the question is whether the variable should be a class variable ..

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: @Svalbard I don't think there's a definitive answer to that, or at least it will be partly opinion based. Looking over your code again though, the `db` object seems to be the entire point of the `Database` class. If `db` isn't made an instance field, your entire `Database` class would appear to just be a class wrapping a factory method that produces `db`s. `create_dashboard` might as well be a loose function. If you do make it an instance field, you might as well make that method the constructor unless you need to delay the creation of the object.

Comment: Oh I agree. This class definition does not make much sense -- I have deleted the other class methods from the example.

Comment: But hm I get it makes a difference for the question though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this question is really just asking, should I make `db` an class variable?

In this specific case, I think you should. Your class is called `Dashboard`, so it probably represents a dashboard of some kind. It would make sense to store the data that the dashboard is displaying inside the object (part of the object state), right?

Also, I think you should call `create_dashboard` in `__init__` because when you initialise a `Dashboard` you would expect it to populate with some default data, right?

If `db` were not a class variable, your class' name would have been "`DashboardCreator`", as all it does is creating dashboards that can display data of a certain size.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted a little discussion from good coders and this helps.

Comment: @Svalbard If you think my answer helps you, please consider accepting it!